# MEA triazine and formaldehyde reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have been making a formulation of roughly 50/50 MEA triazine (CAS no. 4719-04-4) and 37% formalin, with a <1% of a benzalkonium chloride.

The formulation has been pretty stable, but it has occurred that after being subjected to strong agitation it suddenly starts reacting increasing the temperature to more than 100ºC and giving off fumes that smell very strongly like amine.

What I mean by strong agitation is the sloshing of transporting it in a tanker truck filled up to 70% of its capacity and/or filling a tank from the top letting a stream of the product fall the height of the tank.

Thanks!

Comment: Your formulation is MEA-triazine and aqueous formaldehyde or MEA + formaldehyde to get MEA-triazine? Please elaborate your formulation. Also, what chemical is transported by the truck before you put your formulation?

Comment: "Free formaldehyde can boost the capacity and breakthrough efficiency. However, it makes triazine degradation for shorter shelf life as well."  Quoted from this reference https://prism.ucalgary.ca/handle/1880/112374

Comment: Thank you for your answers!
The formulation is actually aqueous MEA triazine + aqueous formaldehyde. It has no free MEA.